# How to use platform-express and platform-fastify together

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs

My purpose is to upload file via nestjs application using package `@types/multer`.

But the problem is that official [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload) says:

[image]

As soon as i started to write my application, i decided to use FastifyAdaptor as primary engine.

```
const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    BackendAdminModule,
    new FastifyAdapter({
      logger: true
    }))
```

And all my routes working on fastify engine.

Is there any possible solution to use both platforms(fastify and express)

Or instanciate somehow for 1 particular route an `express` engine to make it possible to upload and validate file/files via `@types/multer` package?

Any possible solutions that might be useful in my case, thanks in advance!

Comment: you can use both but in two separated nestjs apps, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 7/23/2022 I've published [`@nest-lab/fastify-multer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nest-lab/fastify-multer). You should be able to use it exactly like the [`MulterModule` from NestJS](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload) just make sure you import `FastifyMulterModule` somewhere to register the content parser for `multipart/form-data`. Then you can use the `FileInterceptor` from `@nest-lab/fastify-multer` and get the same file parsing as you would in express.

Comment: Your package looks awesome! I've tried to use your package but for some reason i have fastify-plugin error. It seems that, fastify-multer uses fastify plugin that is incompatible with fastify-multer itself. Maybe you have seen such kind of error and know what to do?
`Error: fastify-plugin: fastify-multer - expected '>= 3.0.0' fastify version, '2.10.0' is installed
`

Comment: `nest-lab/fastify-multer` uses `@nestjs/platform-fastify@^9` which uses `fastify^4`. You appear to be using `fastify@2.10.0`, which won't be compatible. You could take the code and install an older version of `fastify-multer` and make your own pipe, or upgrade your packages

Comment: I have installed `@nestjs/platform-fastify@^9.0.5`. Meanwhile `fastify-multer` is version `2.0.3` (latest version). And i do not quite understand why it won't work on bootstrap. Additionaly I've installled `fastify` to your package with version `4.3.0` and it still doesn't work

Comment: Hmm, with what you've got package wise that should all be fine. Are you getting the same error, or a different one now

Comment: Unfortunately the same error occured

Comment: If you can provide access to your code I can take a look. This should be a straightforward integration

Comment: I've created github repo. I've tried to use you part of the project as npm package, so it modified a little bit in `package.json`. Here is the [link](https://github.com/S1ngle322/fastify-multer-nestjs). The main problem is that, when i trying to make npm install in another project, where i'm using you multer as npm package, it shows an error that i've provided above `error: fastify-plugin`. Thanks in advance!